# How to remove "row" separators/dividers from a List in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, list, swiftui

I'm trying to remove the "row" separators (known as dividers in SwiftUI) from a `List` in SwiftUI.

I went through the `List` documentation, but I haven't been able to find a modifier for that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Simple rewording to make the post more understandable

Comment: Kuya's edit makes sense. I'm having the same issue which is how my search engine lead me here. The original author wants to remove the dividing lines that come by default with the `List` view.

Comment: @Schiopu Evgheni please mark an answer as accepted and don't let a question be open for years. Thanks

Answer (score 32):

## iOS 15:

This year Apple introduced a new modifier `.listRowSeparator` that can be used to style the separators. you can pass `.hidden` to hide it:

```
List {
    ForEach(items, id:\.self) { 
        Text("Row \($0)")
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
    }
}
```

---

## iOS 14

Apple introduced `LazyVStack` In iOS 14. you may consider using it instead of list for this:

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        ForEach((1...100), id: \.self) {
           Text("Placeholder \($0)")
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `LazyVStack` is lazy and doesn't render all rows all the time. So they are very performant and suggested by Apple itself in WWDC 2020.

---

## iOS 13

There is a `UITableView` behind SwiftUI's `List` for iOS. So to remove

### Extra separators (below the list):

you need a `tableFooterView` and to remove

### All separators (including the actual ones):

you need `separatorStyle` to be `.none`

```
init() {
    // To remove only extra separators below the list:
    UITableView.appearance().tableFooterView = UIView()

    // To remove all separators including the actual ones:
    UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
}

var body: some View {
    List {
        Text("Item 1")
        Text("Item 2")
        Text("Item 3")
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion for iOS 14 with Xcode 12.0 beta 2 (ScrollView / LazyVStack), but it still shows the cell separators. Additionally, List still has the same separators.

Comment: Replacing List with Scrollview with VStack messes with the NavigationView with large title

Comment: ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        ForEach((1...100), id: \.self) {
           Text("Placeholder \($0)")
        }
    }
}

Its nicely done my job on iOS 14

Answer (score 14):

## iOS 13 builds only

while this solution works correctly let's clean up the work using
`ViewModifier`

```
public struct ListSeparatorStyleNoneModifier: ViewModifier {
    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.onAppear {
            UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
        }.onDisappear {
            UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .singleLine
        }
    }
}
```

now let's make a small extension that would help to hide the details

```
extension View {
    public func listSeparatorStyleNone() -> some View {
        modifier(ListSeparatorStyleNoneModifier())
    }
}
```

As you can see, we’ve wrapped our appearance setting code into a neat little view modifier.
you can declare  it directly  now

```
List {
    Text("1")
    Text("2")
    Text("3")
}.listSeparatorStyleNone()
```

Comment: Great answer, gonna run with this!

Comment: This solution doesn't work when you have a 2nd list presented as sheet and you don't want to hide separator in that 2nd list.

Answer (score 10):

You may use `ForEach` within a `ScrollView` instead of `List` for dynamic views without any styling

Comment: This doesn't work if the `ScrollView` is inside a `VStack`

Comment: This doesn't lazy display like a list either.

Comment: Use a `LazyVStack` for lazy loading

Answer (score 6):

## iOS 13 builds only:

Adding `UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .clear` for initializer

```
struct SomeView: View {
  init() {
        UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .clear
    }
}
```

I hope you to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 6):

## iOS 13 builds only:

The current workaround is to remove them via `UIAppearance`:

```swift
UITableView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: 
    [UIHostingController<ContentView>.self]
).separatorStyle = .none
```

Answer (score 5):

## iOS 13 builds only:

See existing answers using `UITableView.appearance()`.

⚠️ Be aware that in the iOS 14 SDK, `List` does not appear to be backed by `UITableView`. See the alternate solution below:

## iOS 14 Xcode 12 Beta 1 only:

I do have a pure SwiftUI solution for iOS 14, but who knows how long it's going to continue working for. It relies on your content being the same size (or larger) than the default list row and having an opaque background.

⚠️ This does not work for iOS 13 builds.

Tested in Xcode 12 beta 1:

```swift
yourRowContent
  .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 16))
  .frame(
    minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity,
    minHeight: 44,
    alignment: .leading
  )
  .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
  .background(Color.white)
```

Or if you're looking for a reusable `ViewModifier`:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct HideRowSeparatorModifier: ViewModifier {

  static let defaultListRowHeight: CGFloat = 44

  var insets: EdgeInsets
  var background: Color

  init(insets: EdgeInsets, background: Color) {
    self.insets = insets

    var alpha: CGFloat = 0
    UIColor(background).getWhite(nil, alpha: &alpha)
    assert(alpha == 1, "Setting background to a non-opaque color will result in separators remaining visible.")
    self.background = background
  }

  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .padding(insets)
      .frame(
        minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity,
        minHeight: Self.defaultListRowHeight,
        alignment: .leading
      )
      .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
      .background(background)
  }
}

extension EdgeInsets {

  static let defaultListRowInsets = Self(top: 0, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 16)
}

extension View {

  func hideRowSeparator(
    insets: EdgeInsets = .defaultListRowInsets,
    background: Color = .white
  ) -> some View {
    modifier(HideRowSeparatorModifier(
      insets: insets,
      background: background
    ))
  }
}

struct HideRowSeparator_Previews: PreviewProvider {

  static var previews: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(0..<10) { _ in
        Text("Text")
          .hideRowSeparator()
      }
    }
    .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is correct answer for iOS 14. For iOS 13 builds answers with UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none work fine.

Comment: It's not **removing** the separator. It is just adding a `.background(Color.white)` on a view on top of the separator and blocks the view. try `.background(Color.red.opacity(0.2))` to see yourself.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini if you check out the code I posted, you'll see that I'm asserting exactly the same thing! Thanks so much for being so specific about the definition of `removing`!

Comment: this solution still shows the separator on top of the first row in list

Comment: This is asinine. Not your code - the NEED for that code. 

SwiftUI continues to be not ready for prime time. :(

Comment: Apple really rushed SwiftUI by at least 2 years. So much stuff missing

Comment: This works, but it's more like a "rowBackground" that covers the separator (and covers the `listRowBackground` if set). To handle anything over than a white row, I'd recommend renaming the extension to `rowBackground(color: _)` to allow setting the color.  If you need to add a separator, you can then add it to view itself.

Answer (score 5):

From: Swiftui Views Mastery Book SwiftUI 2.0 Mark Moeykens

```
.listStyle(SidebarListStyle()) # IOS 14
```

> You can apply this new list style which will remove the separator lines.

Comment: Worked on iOS14 but how to hide `>` this simbol at the end of row ...

Comment: this should be the accepted answer! Also, I was able to just do `.listStyle(.sidebar)`

Answer (score 1):

## For iOS13，iOS14，iOS15，and remove the separator at the top of the first cell

##### Add viewModifier

```
extension View {
    /// 隐藏 List 中的 分割线
    func hideRowSeparator(insets: EdgeInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0),
                          background: Color = .white) -> some View {
        modifier(HideRowSeparatorModifier(insets: insets, background: background))
    }
}

struct HideRowSeparatorModifier: ViewModifier {

  static let defaultListRowHeight: CGFloat = 44

  var insets: EdgeInsets
  var background: Color

  init(insets: EdgeInsets, background: Color) {
    self.insets = insets

    var alpha: CGFloat = 0
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        UIColor(background).getWhite(nil, alpha: &alpha)
        assert(alpha == 1, "Setting background to a non-opaque color will result in separators remaining visible.")
    }
    self.background = background
  }

  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
        .padding(insets)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: Self.defaultListRowHeight)
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .overlay(
            VStack {
                HStack {}
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height: 1)
                .background(background)
                Spacer()
                HStack {}
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height: 1)
                .background(background)
            }
            .padding(.top, -1)
        )
  }
}
```

##### Usage

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< 30) { item in
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 30) {
                    Text("Hello, world!：\(item)").padding()
                }
                .hideRowSeparator(background: .white)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
}
```

##### You can find here

https://github.com/wangrui460/HiddenListLine4SwiftUI

## iOS / SwiftUI 技术交流

我创建了一个 微信 iOS 技术交流群、SwiftUI 技术交流群，欢迎小伙伴们加入一起交流学习~

可以加我微信我拉你进去（备注iOS），我的微信号 wr1204607318