# How can I change the colour of separator in list of SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui, ios13, swiftui-list

I created a list in SwiftUI. I want to change the color or remove the separator as, In UIKit, we can easily change the color of separator in TableView.

Below is the code and UI(image) of the list in SwiftUI

```
@State private var users = ["Paul", "Taylor", "Adele"]

var body: some View {

    List(){
                ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
                    HStack{
                        Image("helmet").resizable().frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .leading)
                        VStack(alignment : .leading){
                            Text(user).font(.custom("SFProText-Semibold", size: 14))
                            Text("Blu Connect").font(.custom("SFProText-Semibold.ttf", size: 11))
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: delete)

            }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @matt tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.red

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
var body: some View {
        UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = UIColor.blue
        return List(){
            ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
                HStack{
                    Image("helmet").resizable().frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .leading)
                    VStack(alignment : .leading){
                        Text(user).font(.custom("SFProText-Semibold", size: 14))
                        Text("Blu Connect").font(.custom("SFProText-Semibold.ttf", size: 11))
                    }
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: delete)

        }
    }
```

This is a kind of global variable, so you are changing the separator colour in all UITableViews from your app (List and Form are using UITableViews under the hood)

Comment: Where I can write this? In SwiftUI class this is not working.

Comment: I am not using UIKit at all. So how can I access this UITableView.appearance().separatorColor and where?

Comment: Can I know what is the concept of this solution? Maybe some articles or documents where I understand how exactly this worked...  (List and Form are using UITableViews under the hood) This is a nice explanation in short. I want to know more than this.

Comment: damn SwiftUI, this is not working on iOS 14 #@$@#%$@#^%^

Answer (score 1):

**2021 – Xcode 13 / SwiftUI 3**

Change color of separator:

```
.listRowSeparatorTint(Color.pink)
```

Hide separator:

```
.listRowSeparator(.hidden)
```

Answer (score 0):

## iOS 15

From this year, you can apply color to any separator individually with `listRowSeparatorTintColor` modifier like:

[image: Demo]

---

## To remove

From iOS 15, you can use `listRowSeparator` modifier by passing `hidden`.
Please read **[this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58426643/5623035)** for more information and samples.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this on older versions of iOS checkout [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect)

You can then do something like the following to change the separator color to red:

```swift
List {
    // ...
}
.introspectTableView { tableView in
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.red
}
```

for new versions see @MojtabaHosseini's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67891622/2974621)

Answer (score -1):

You can also swap out the List() element for a ScrollView() element.