# How to remove List Separator lines in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, list, swiftui, separator, ios14

So the question is pretty simple and it's in the title. I want to remove the line separator in SwiftUI iOS 14. Previously, I was using
 `UITableView().appearance().separatorStyle = .none`
and that used to do the job in iOS 13. Now, however, it doesn't work. Any update or idea on how to make it work? Thanks :)

Comment: Well, there is no more `UITableView` underneath... no more hucks ))

Comment: @SchmidtyApps posted a solution that I've confirmed works! But the answer was deleted by a moderator and I can't undelete it. See https://github.com/SchmidtyApps/SwiftUIListSeparator

Comment: @Asperi what do you mean there is no more UITableView underneath - there is one still

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible solution. Tested with Xcode 12b.

[image: demo]

```
List {
    ForEach(0..<3) { _ in
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!").padding(.leading)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground)))
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Color(UIColor.systemBackground))` instead of `Color.white`?

Comment: In addition, you may want to apply negative edge insets in some cases. `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(.init(top: -1, leading: -1, bottom: -1, trailing: -1)))`.

Comment: How can you do this without modifying the insets? Removing all the padding makes the list look bad.

Comment: @JordanH You can set the list style to `.listStyle(InsetListStyle())`

Comment: love this solution and it's working beautifully on simulator (XCode 12, running iOS 13 and 14) however, it doesn't work on my actual device (iPhone XS, iOS 14.2). The list separators are all showing up for some strange reason. Anyone else faced the same?

Comment: I use button in my list cell. After adding this the highlighted color has gone from my buttons.

Comment: What if you actually need to use .listRowInsets with non-zero values for insets ?

Answer (score 10):

Merged @asperi, @akmin and @zrfrank answer into one thing. In my experience `List` is more reliable and efficient than `LazyVStack`, so I use still use `List` for anything complex requiring reliability.

```swift
extension View {
    func listRow() -> some View {
        self.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: -1, leading: -1, bottom: -1, trailing: -1))
            .background(Color(.systemBackground))
    }
}

List {
    Color.red
         .listRow()


    Color.green
         .listRow()
}
```

Comment: `LazyVStack ` doesn't fit if you want to have list sections.

Comment: This works for me. List + some View (not LazyVStack)

Comment: On iOS 14 it works like a charm! No LazyVStack but only List + view.
Thanks man! I was gettin' mad!

Comment: I'm horrified that this works for iOS 14 and seems to do nothing on iOS 15, but that's the way it plays out.

Answer (score 9):

## iOS 15:

This year Apple introduced a new modifier `.listRowSeparator` that can be used to style the separators. you can pass `.hidden` to hide it:

```
List(items, id:\.self) {
    Text("Row \($0)")
        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
}
```

Also you can set each separator to any color by settings `listRowSeparatorTintColor` as I mentioned [here in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67891622/5623035):

[image: Demo]

### iOS 14

Follow [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62598818/5623035)

Comment: Downvoted as this doesn't actually answer the question of how to do it in SwiftUI 2.0 on iOS 14

Answer (score 7):

How I made a list that works on both iOS 14 and iOS 13, It shows no separators and extra margins

```
struct NoButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
    }
}

struct ListWithoutSepatorsAndMargins<Content: View>: View {
        let content: () -> Content
    
        var body: some View {
            if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                        self.content()
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(NoButtonStyle())
                }
            } else {
                List {
                    self.content()
                }
                .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
                .buttonStyle(NoButtonStyle())
            }
        }
    }
```

Sample Usage -

```
ListWithoutSepatorsAndMargins {
    ForEach(0..<5) { _ in
      Text("Content")
    }
}
```

in case you've more components in list, wrap them in Group

```
                ListWithoutSepatorsAndMargins {
                    Group {
                            self.groupSearchResults()
                            self.myGroups()
                            self.exploreGroups()
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Hope this helps someone, I wasted a lot of time in such minor thing, Apple is trying to push us hard to use LazyVStack, it seems

Comment: this solution is harmful, because LazyVStack works with cells in a completely different manner, than List. You can check CPU load when scrolling those cells. If the cell is something more than Text(“hello test”), you will see peak load while scrolling

Comment: CPU usage goes up a bit while scrolling but comes back down instantly as things stabilize, which used to happen in UITableView as well, I have pretty heavy cells in my app and very big lists, It has never caused a lag in scrolling or crash for us, we saw no issues so far but use at your own risk!

Comment: @Lonkly why do you think it can be a problem?

Comment: @Zapko how do you think, what is the main difference between StackView and TableView in UIKit? The same, that List and LazyVStack have. TableView reuses cells, LazyVStack does not. So when you have more elements that fit the screen, and the layout is more complex than Text("Content") you will get extreme slowness and lags. Therefore providing the solution that is called ListWithoutSeparators{} and making it a LazyVStack inside is super harmful.

Comment: by using lazy vstack you lose other List benefits like edit state, swipe to delete gesture etc.

Comment: I have solved it using List here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64028051/14327378, please check it out if you want List :)

Answer (score 5):

I found this simple solution on the Apple Developer forums. It's working for me on 14.4:

```
List {
   ...
}.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
```

This seems to add a tiny bit of padding around the edges. If that's a problem for you, you could try some negative padding.

Comment: I think it's the best solution right now, very elegant!

Answer (score 3):

Based on [average Joe's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/667700/average-joe) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64350901/2074238) I ended up with the following modifier:

```
struct ListSeparatorNone: ViewModifier {

    var backgroundColor: Color = Color(.systemBackground)
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: -1, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .background(backgroundColor)
    }
}
```

The view extension:

```
extension View {
    func listSeparatorNone(backgroundColor: Color = Color(.systemBackground)) -> some View {
        self.modifier(ListSeparatorNone(backgroundColor: backgroundColor))
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
List {
    ForEach(viewModel.countries, id: \.self) { country in
        Text(country)
            .padding(.leading, 10)
    }
    .listSeparatorNone()
}
```

Comment: sometimes works, sometimes doesnt'

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a lot of cells, and therefore don't need to rely on a LazyVStack for performance, you can fallback to a ScrollView + VStack:

```
ScrollView {
  VStack {
    Row1()
    Row2()
    Row3()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also call this function at the end of your VStack (that is inner the List).

It will be an overlay on List Seperator on iOS 14 :)

```
private func hideDefaultListSeperator() -> some View {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(colorScheme == .light ? Color.white : Color.black)
        .frame(maxHeight: 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I figured out a solution that works on both iOS 13 and iOS 14 and gives a simple list and uses List on both iOS.

```
struct ListWithoutSepatorsAndMargins<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let content: () -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            self.content()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                .background(Color.white)
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .buttonStyle(NoButtonStyle())
    }
}

struct NoButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
    }
```

and do the following in SceneDelegate.swift to remove default grey selection of cells

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
    UITableView.appearance().allowsSelection = false
   .......
```

and we can use it the following way

```
ListWithoutSepatorsAndMargins {
    ForEach(0..<5) { _ in
      Text("Content")
    }
}

ListWithoutSepatorsAndMargins {
     Group {
        self.groupSearchResults()
        self.myGroups()
        self.exploreGroups()
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: And where are we supposed to find `SceneDelegate`?

Comment: add it on the launch of your app, the first piece of code that gets executed

Comment: in later versions of ios I am getting a default spacing between cells which can be removed by doing the following

Comment: `List {
  
   self.content()
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
    .background(Color.white)
  
  }
  .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
  .buttonStyle(NoButtonStyle())
  .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 1)`

Comment: the extra   `.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 1)` from the previous solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for iOS 14:

```
struct MyRowView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
      // Background color of the Row. It will spread under the entire row.
      Color(.systemBackground)
      NavigationLink(destination: Text("Details")) {
        EmptyView()
      }
      .opacity(0) // Hide the Disclosure Indicator

      Text("Go to Details").padding(.leading)
    }
    // These 2 lines hide the row separators
    .padding(.horizontal, -16) // Removes default horizontal padding
    .padding(.vertical, -6)    // Removes default vertical padding
  }
}
```

The enclosing List should have this modifier

> .listStyle(PlainListStyle())

The upside of this solution over using a **LazyVStack** is that you can still use the Edit capabilities of the **List**.

This solution relies unfortunately on hard-coded values to remove the system default paddings on each row. Hopefully SwiftUI 3.0 will provide simple .separatorStyle(.none) and .accessoryType(.none) modifiers.

The code to remove the Disclosure Indicators comes from: https://www.appcoda.com/hide-disclosure-indicator-swiftui-list/

Answer (score -1):

Thank for @asperi, @akmin and @zrfrank and @averageJoe 's answers.

Here is another improved method works in iOS 14 and 15.

```
extension View {
    func hideListRowSeperator() -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            return AnyView(self.listRowSeparator(.hidden))
        } else {
            return AnyView(self.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: -1, leading: -1, bottom: -1, trailing: -1))
                .background(Color(.systemBackground)))
        }
    }
}
```

Use example

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(0..<3) { _ in
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .padding(.leading)
                .hideListRowSeperator()
        }
    }
    .listStyle(.plain)
}
```

Answer (score -5):

The above answer work for me, you have to set only below both function:

`.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())`

`.background(Color.white)`