# How to remove the separator in a single row of List in SwiftUI?

Tags: list, swiftui, separator, sections

From this question I know how to remove all separators from the `List`: [How to remove "row" separators from a List in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56489099/how-to-remove-row-separators-from-a-list-in-swiftui)

But my list has multiple sections and I only want to remove the separators in a single section/row.

Anyone knows how we can do that with SwiftUI under iOS 13.

## Edit 1:

I already tried to remove all separators and add a small rectangle as a separator where I need (as suggested by @Asperi), but then I have a problem with default editing mode, the UI is off.

[image]

Comment: Remove default, add programmatically own separator (just 1pt Rectangle or Divider, etc) where needed.

Comment: @Asperi forget to say that I tried that already but the UI in editing mode is off. I edited my question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
.onAppear { UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none }
```

Comment: this removes all separators, please read my question again.